# Extract a gpg file in a nexus 7?

Tags: ssh, terminal, shell, encryption

I want to extract a gpg file (passphrase only, no key), with a Nexus 7.  It's just a gpg with a txt file inside.

How do I get it to the nexus 7 and then even if I can extract it, how do I get to it with a text editor?  I can scp it from my lan server to get it here (the n7).

I have the juicessh installed in the n7, I figured that's a good place to start, but how would I even do it from within juicessh- can I login from localhost? I tried loggin in to 127.0.0.1 but the ssh connection failed (perhaps not a surprise).

Seems like a simple thing but it's apparently not.

thanks

Comment: This would be on topic for [android.se], but as it stands, it's too broad for migration. For more information, see the [help].

Comment: Ok- I don't know how else to ask the question. Too broad?

Comment: I mean unless you want me to just narrow it to "I want to extract a gpg file (passphrase only, no key), with a Nexus 7. It's just a gpg with a txt file inside." And no other information?

Comment: ...I took a closer look at the question and it's actually not too broad, but as written, it's a bit confusing. Organizing the text of the question to make it more to the point would make it easier to understand.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to make it more clear.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159456/decrypting-gpg-file-on-android